# Can I perform a random-effect-within-between analysis on SPSS?

Tags: mixed-model

I'm analyzing quality of governance on food security indicators for the last 3 years for 74 countries. To be precise, I am interested in a within-country variation across time (before and during the Covid-19 pandemic), as well as the between-country variation. This choice was informed by [Bell et. al.’s (2019) article.](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/134123/10/Bell2018_Article_FixedAndRandomEffectsModelsMak.pdf)

REWB is a specific type of mixed effects model but since it is a recent method, I am not sure how to go about it on SPSS (codes for R are available but I can only use SPSS)

Anyone knows how to perform REWB on SPSS?

Comment: Probably. But you might want to give a bit more explanation about what REWB is.